# iPhone storyboard UINavigationController Tabbar disappear

Tags: iphone, uinavigationcontroller, uitabbarcontroller, uistoryboard

I already posted this question, but nobody maybe understand and answer it.
I tried web surfing, and studying in several days, but unfortunately I cannot find the answer.
The only thing I can do just now is to depend stackoverflow guys.
I build simple app with storyboard without any code.
My storyboard is as follows.

[image]

When I run the app, and move to "ViewController A", tabbar is disappeared suddenly.
I really wonder why it does.
How can I show tabbar in this screen?

current screen "ViewController A" which tabbar disappeared.

[image]

Comment: i've not mac now, but click on storyboard and viewcontrollerA, you must define in proprerty the father tabbar if i remember right

Answer (score 1):

Add a navigation Controller for View controller A.

Take Storyboard , select View controller . Editor->Embed In->NavigationController

Answer (score 0):

Yes it will rightly disappear, you need to embedd `UINavigationController` to every rootcontroller of the `tabBarController` ie viewController item 1 and viewController item 2.
Currently what's happening is that you are pushing viewController A to the navigationController which is seen behind the FIRST SCREEN WITHOUT TABBAR Controller.

Comment: I embedded UINavigationController to viewController item1.
As a result, In the ViewController A, tabbar is shown, but in the viewcontroller item1 and viewcontrollerA screens, 2 navigation bars are shown. How can I show only one navigation bar in the one screen?